# Binding a table row's button visibility to a function in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to figure out how to change the visibility of a button in a table, based on whether on not a specific item exists in an observableArray().

For example, I have a Student/Course roster where there is a list of all students and a list of enrolled students for each course.  I want to make a "Add" button become invisible next to the All Students list, if the student appears in the current EnrolledStudents observableArray. I have, in my view:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: AllStudents">
       <tr>
           <td><button data-bind="click: $parent.add, visible: $parent.isEnrolled">Add</button></td>
           <td data-bind="text: StudentId"></td>
           <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
           <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Where I iterate through AllStudents and display the information as well as an "Add" button. However, I have a isEnrolled function to determine whether or not the specific student is enrolled in the currently selected class. Here is my function:

```
 this.isEnrolled = ko.computed(function (item) {

                    var index = $.inArray(item, self.EnrolledStudents);
                    if (index > -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
```

The thing is, ko.computed() does not pass the associated object into this function as expected, which makes `item = undefined`... What do I need to do in order to make this function work for each student in the table?

Here is my entire ViewModel.. No jsFiddle cause the ajax calls won't work.

```
 function AppViewModel() {
                this.AllStudents = ko.observableArray();
                this.AllCourses = ko.observableArray();
                this.EnrolledStudents = ko.observableArray();
                this.CurrentCourse = ko.observable("1");


                var self = this;

                this.add = function (item) {
                    $.post('/api/Course/AddStudentToCourse?courseId='+self.CurrentCourse()+'&studentId='+item.Id, function (data) {
                        alert("Success");
                        console.log(data);
                        self.EnrolledStudents.push(data);

                    });
                }

                this.remove = function (item) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/Course/DeleteStudentFromCourse?courseId='+self.CurrentCourse()+'&studentId='+item.Id,
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data == true) {
                                self.EnrolledStudents.destroy(item);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                this.isEnrolled = ko.computed(function () {

                    var index = $.inArray(item, self.EnrolledStudents);
                    if (index > -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }, this);

                $.get('/api/Course/AllStudents', this.AllStudents);
                $.get('/api/Course/AllCourses', this.AllCourses);



                $('select').change(function () {
                    self.CurrentCourse($('select option:selected').val());

                    if (self.CurrentCourse() != "") {
                        $.get('/api/Course/StudentsByCourse', { id: self.CurrentCourse() }, self.EnrolledStudents);
                    }
                });

            }

            ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: Can you please show your whole view model or make a fiddle?

Comment: Are you checking whether the student is enrolled or whether something else is true?

Answer (score 2):

The `visible` binding does not pass in the current object as a parameter by default like the `click` binding.  What you would need to do is something like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: AllStudents">
   <tr>
       <td><button data-bind="click: $parent.add, visible: $parent.checkIsEnrolled( $data )">Add</button></td>
       <td data-bind="text: StudentId"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then add this function to your view model to verify the current object is enrolled:

```
self.checkIsEnrolled = function( item ) {
     var index = self.EnrolledStudents.indexOf( item );
     if (index > -1) {
          return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

One more issue unrelated to the visible was the remove function should actually use the `remove` method rather than the `destroy`.

And here is an updated fiddle using this function:

http://jsfiddle.net/7J8XR/4/

The full listing of context variables is here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: I am getting this error when I try that `Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "visible: function (){return $parent.isEnrolled($data) }"
Message: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.`

Comment: I don't want to "write" to the isEnrolled variable.. I just want the context of the data to do the search

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I just updated the answer to use a function rather than the computed.

Comment: oh, so you just use a normal function then? Ok sounds easy enought

Comment: for this particular instance I probably would if the visible property isn't tied directly to the object currently in the loop.  Another option is to make the isEnrolled a computed within the child (Student) model and have that inspect the parent to see if it's within the Enrolled array

Comment: So I changed my code and now it appears that the IsEnrolled function never gets called.. So all my buttons are `display:none;` automatically

Comment: Could you post this to a jsfiddle and just spoof the ajax data?  it's easier to nail it down that way

Comment: here is my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/7J8XR/1/, however, now that I spoofed the ajax, something doesn't seem to be working

Comment: so when I take out the visible part it renders correctly, http://jsfiddle.net/7J8XR/2/

Comment: Matt, ignore my answer (but perhaps interesting for future reference), to get this fiddle working, you need to reference Jquery in the fiddle settings and reference knockout.js via a cdn in external libraries, plus you need to negate the isEnrolled with ! (if not isEnrolled), http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/uCgfL/

Answer (score 1):

****not an appropriate answer for Matt's question, as it doesn't fit with how he's retrieving the enrolled students - I have left this here for interest, see comment *******

As an alternative (as it achieves your goal and keeps things clean), you could add an isEnrolled observable property to the student when you first create the AllStudents observable array:

```
this.AllStudents=ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(students,function(student){
     student.isEnrolled = ko.observable(false);
    return student;
}));
```

Then, when you click add, set the isEnrolled property to true:

```
this.add = function (item) {

   item.isEnrolled(true);
   self.EnrolledStudents.push(item);
}
```

Your html on the table row will then work like this:

```
<tr data-bind="visible:!isEnrolled()">
```

And finally on your remove click, set isEnrolled to false (and use .remove(item) instead of destroy as pointed out by hereswhatIdid in his answer:

```
this.remove = function (item) {

    item.isEnrolled(false);               
    self.EnrolledStudents.remove(item);
}
```

Fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/823v5/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Matt, on second reading of your question and viewmodel, my answer doesn't fit - though hopefully of interest anyways.  I have answered your comment in hereswhatidid answer about getting that fiddle working (fiddle setup issue, and also needing the !) regards.